# Setting default precision for all decimal numbers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to force Rails to output all decimal numbers with a certain precision? All of the decimal fields in my database are currency amounts, so I'd like decimal numbers to show by default with a precision of 2 (i.e. 2.40). I know I can use a helper function like "number_to_currency" to do this to each individual number, but that seems a bit tedious and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about overriding "to_s" on Float having possible unforeseen side-effects, your next best bet is probably to just create a new method, but still as a core extension. Something like this:

```
class Float
    def c
        sprintf('%.2f', self)
    end
end
```

Then can't have any unforeseen consequences, and then anywhere you'd want to display the number with two decimal places, you'd just call `.c`. For example:

```
message = "The account balance is $#{amount.c}."
```

Not automatic, but not much extra typing, and no possible side-effects that overriding to_s could potentially cause.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add new information instead of adding a second answer.

Comment: That's helpful, Ben. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy, I know, I usually do if I just have an edit or want to change my answer, but in this case I thought both answers had their separate merits, especially considering the original poster said he did not want to mess with ruby. I still wanted to leave that answer alive though for reference in case others come across this post and prefer the more direct monkey patch.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't mind monkey patching ruby, you can add a something like this (put it in an initializer at "/config/initializers/core_extensions.rb"):

```
class Float
    def to_s
        sprintf('%.2f', self)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather not mess with ruby, though.

Comment: @Jude, Well, it's not really "messing with ruby" -- it's just a monkey patch that changes the behavior for you app. If there's never any instance in your app that you won't want to display a float with two decimals of precision, I don't see how that could harm.